# How can i solve this error using "Laravel Follow"

Tags: laravel

So i'm trying to make a like system for my imageshare.
For that i tried to use the "Laravel Follow" from overtrue but it's giving me problems.

Everytime i try to use the functions that he says in his GitHub page it always gives me "Call to undefined method App\Models\Photo::needsToApproveFollowRequests()".

This is my User.php

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
    use Overtrue\LaravelFollow\Followable;
    
    
    
    
    class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
    {
        use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, Followable;
    
        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var string[]
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'firstName',
            'lastName',
            'name',
            'email',
            'password',
            
        ];
    
        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password',
            'remember_token',
        ];
    
        /**
         * The attributes that should be cast.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $casts = [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        ];
}
```

And this is the function in my controller where I'm trying to use it:

```
public function getSnatch($id) {
    //Let's try to find the image from database first
    $image = Photo::find($id);

    if(!$image) {
      abort(404);
    }

    $imageThumb = Photo::find($id)->paginate(1);
    $user = User::find($image->user);

    $currentUser = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
    

    // $user = User::where('id', $userID)->first();
    $lastId = Photo::where('id', '<', $image->id)->max('id');
    $nextId = Photo::where('id', '>', $image->id)->min('id');
    
    // $nextPageNumber = $image->id + 1;
    
    $maxId = Photo::find($id)->max('id');
    $minId = Photo::find($id)->min('id');
    
    // $imageCount = count(DB::table('photos')->get());

    // ddd($nextId);



    $likeImage = $currentUser->toggleFollow($image);

    $totalLikes = $image->followers();
    

    if ($lastId < $minId) {
      $lastId = $maxId;
    }
    
    if ($nextId === NULL) {
      $nextId = $minId;
    }
    
    
    //If found, we load the view and pass the image info asparameter, else we redirect to main page with errormessage
    if($image) {
      return View::make('tpl.permalink')
      ->with('image', $image)
      ->with('lastId', $lastId)
      ->with('nextId', $nextId)
      ->with('user', $user)
      ->with('imageThumb', $imageThumb)
      ->with('currentUser', $currentUser)
      ->with('likeImage', $likeImage)
      ->with('totalLikes', $totalLikes);
    } else {
      return Redirect::to('/')->with('error','Image not found');
    }
}
```

Everything in the composer is well installed.
I also tried to delete the vendor folder, clear the cache of the composer and make composer install again, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the method in your model that uses `Followable` trait.

```
public function needsToApproveFollowRequests()
{
    // Your custom logic here
    return (bool) $this->private;
}
```

Comment: Still gives the same error :(

Comment: @Jonypaul you override the method on User Model or Photo Model? Because the one that gives an error is the Photo model.

Comment: Now i did in the right one and it doesn't give that problem anymore.
Still doesn't work, but it is because this code doesn't suit well my project. :(
Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Jonypaul Please consider marking my answer as correct if it was helpful :).

Comment: I'm sorry, i completely forgot after to do it!